# ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 150528 elements to shape [224,150528]

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, classification, valueerror

I am new to tensorflow and im still learning so I apologize if I am missing something obvious. So basically my problem is that I am trying to set up a simple image classifier with tensorflow in python, I figured out how to create my datasets and such but now I am just trying to get the training process going but the problem is that whenever I try I get this error

> ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 150528 elements to shape [224,150528] (33718272 elements) for 'dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/Image/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [224,224,3], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [224,150528].

I looked at some other posts I found here on stack overflow on this problem and they said that he was reshaping his data incorrectly and from what ive read from my error I have the same problem, the thing is I am using a premade estimator and I myself am not calling any reshaping functions in my code, the estimator is doing that for me I assume so how can I go about resolving this error? Thanks for any help here is my code

Training Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
from DatasetCreator import DatasetCreator

trainingImagesPath = "TrainingImages"

#Loads the image data
def load_image(addr):
    imageDimensions = (224, 224)
    image = cv2.imread(addr)
    #Resize the image to the size we need
    image = cv2.resize(image, imageDimensions, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)#Convert to RGB color space
    image = image.astype(np.float32)
    print(image.shape)
    return image

#Load in the datasets
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    dataCreator = DatasetCreator()

    trainingDataset = dataCreator.generateDataset(trainingImagesPath)

    #Create a training iterator for getting info from dataset
    trainingIterator = trainingDataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_element = trainingIterator.get_next()

    def train_input_fn():
        with tf.Session(graph = graph) as sess:
            features = sess.run(next_element)

            #Get the image path
            imagePath = str(features["ImagePath"])
            imagePath = imagePath[2:len(imagePath)-1]

            #Get the label
            label = features["ImageLabel"]

            image = load_image(imagePath)#Get image data

            return {"Image": image, "Label": label}


    featureColumns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Image", [224, 224, 3]),
                      tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Label")]

    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
            model_dir = "Model",
            feature_columns = featureColumns,
            hidden_units = [1024, 512, 256],
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    )

    print("Began training")

    estimator.train(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps=1000)
```

Here is my code that creates my training dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from random import shuffle
import glob
import numpy as np


class DatasetCreator:
  def __init__(self):
    pass;

  def generateDataset(self, trainingImagesPath):
    addrs = glob.glob(trainingImagesPath + "/*.jpg")#Get list of paths of all the images in folder

    #Label each address
    labels = [0 if "car" in image else 1 for image in addrs]#Compile list of labels

    # Divide the hata into 60% train, 20% validation, and 20% test
    train_addrs = addrs[0:int(0.6*len(addrs))]
    train_labels = labels[0:int(0.6*len(labels))]
    val_addrs = addrs[int(0.6*len(addrs)):int(0.8*len(addrs))]
    val_labels = labels[int(0.6*len(addrs)):int(0.8*len(addrs))]
    test_addrs = addrs[int(0.8*len(addrs)):]
    test_labels = labels[int(0.8*len(labels)):]

    #Create dataset
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
      {"ImagePath": train_addrs,
       "ImageLabel": train_labels})

    return dataset;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you shouldn't pass the label as a feature column. Can you try removing `tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Label")` from `feature_columns`?

Comment: @kaufmanu I removed it but it still didn't work, i got the same error.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Hello westmkk1, Is your issue resolved now. Else, adding the line, `image = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 224 * 224 * 3])`, before  `return` statement, in `train_input_fn`,  should resolve this error.